# Can I search "Added By/Modified By" with a contact ID instead of a name?

Tags: smartgroups

First, I'm French and my english is not good, sorry.

currently using CiviCRM (4.6.10) production coupled with Joomla (3.5.0) (thanks to this forum), I currently have a problem with the smart group and the search criteria.

Indeed, to add users to the group dynamic I use the search term "Added by" in the Advanced Search section of ChangeLog.

In this field, we can insert only the NAME of the onscreen user. The problem is we have several employees with the same name and therefore the "contacts" of any one of those employees is seen by all who have the same name.

**1) Is it possible to change this search to replace the name with the contact_id the database?**

If this is not possible at present in the database in the table "civicrm_saved_search" the "where_clause" a group for example:

```
( contact_b_log.sort_name LIKE '%dupont%' )
```

**2) Is it not possible to change this "sortName" to match the contact_id collaborator?**

**3) If you see another possible solution?**

Thank you in advance to those who have an idea for my problem,

Lionel

Comment: I think I see where I was confused. Your wrote, "The only other thought is that you could consider another approach, such as, if you are using Drupal you could have your team 'add' contacts through Drupal Webform - and create a Relationship between them." I would edit the last part to say 'and then ***you*** create a relationship between them.'

Answer (score 3):

Bonjour. I think you are using the field in the Change Log, Modified By (Added by) - ie 'Journal of Change' is your translation of the French version of 'Change Log'.
You are right, currently it is just used as a 'text' field. So Advanced Search is not going to help you.
And the field is not currently available in Search Builder either.
And there is no Custom Search for this.

So, if you have developer/funds is to add the feature to one of the above.

Or create an extension that does the above automatically.

The only other thought is that you could consider another approach, such as, if you are using Drupal you could have your team 'add' contacts through Drupal Webform - and create a Relationship between them. The benefits would be that you could then

- search by the Relationship and then create a Smart Group
- use the Permissioned Relationship extension so that user 'Jean' could only see contacts that they added.

Hope some of the above is helpful.

Comment: We've had the problem that when one of our branch leaders is adding a contact, through a drupal form or through civicrm, they aren't able to add a relationship until after the contact is created.  But once they create the contact, they aren't able to access the contact until admin creates a relationships that bumps that newly created contact into a group that the branch leader has access to.  Is there a way to set up a drupal form to bump the new contact into a group that I could assign the branch leader access to?

Comment: Matt - I may be missing the point here but this doesn't seem to relate and hence would be better as a separate question where i think you will get better answers